# Changing the Comport accessed by Qt

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I'm currently setting my Serial port as follows;

```
#define PORT                "COM10"
serial.setPortName(PORT);
```

Whenever I change the port number from 10, Qt can no longer open the port unless I physically change the port accessed via device manager. How can I set the serial port to be whatever I wish (from COM 1 to COM 256)?

Comment: Do not `close()`, `setPortName()` and `open()` work?

Comment: Do you mean I should not close the serial port and delete the line `serial.close();`? I tried that and didn't work. If I try setting the port name again, I lose communication with the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not open whatever port you like, actually there are some available ports on your system depending on the hardware and you can only work with them. The list of available ports could be found using [QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialportinfo.html#availablePorts) :

```
QList<QSerialPortInfo> ports = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
```

You are only allowed to use the ports in the list.

Comment: I counted the ports available in a similar manner and it says just one port is available. Does Qt usually access one port only? I suppose I'm stuck with using device manager if I ever need to change ports/

Comment: Actually your system probably has only one serial port, it has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: Shouldn't I still be able to change the comport name i'm currently using even if one serial port is available?

Comment: @Duanne It's a system-wide name. You can change it only in OS itself (or at least use special low-level API to do that).

Comment: Okay thanks, I assumed that by changing "PORT" to any other COM number I could access any of the ports on my computer. Also do you know if Qt can connect to more than 1 device at a time?

Comment: You can has multiple instances of `QSerialPort` and communicate with devices connected to the system ports.